# Tableau: set priority of extract refresh in tab cmd (command/script)

Tags: cmd, tabs, command, tableau-api

I tried researching this in other places but couldn't find an answer, so hope here someone can help me. I have the following code, which is for updating different workbooks:

```
@echo OFF  
set Binpath="C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\2018.1\extras\Command Line Utility"  
%Binpath%\tabcmd refreshextracts -s https://(mySite) -u (user) -p (password) --no-certcheck --url "workbookWExtract2Refresh" --timeout 1800
```

My question is: where can I add the priority of the workbook update? In the example in the code there wouldn't be any problem, since it is only one workbook, however I have some code with 10 workbooks, even more, and some have a much higher priority than others, thus, trying to find a way to add the priority to the code above.

(If I am not clear enough or I need to improve the question, please do tell so I can do so)

Comment: I don't know the exact answer here, but can you confirm if you have checked whether or not refresh tasks are firing off in a different order than in your script? (ie: Script contains Extract A, B, then C - __Background Tasks AdminView__ shows Extracts executed in order B, C, then A.) Or are you able to confirm that they are firing off in the right order?

Comment: I /think/ they are running in the order I put them in the script. However, that's why I am trying to search for an option to put the priority on the script, since when you do that manually you can add the priority (50 as default) to a refresh task; want to do that, but in the script. As additional info, can't confirm and/or check that since I am not the one running the process itself, just the one that had to do the script

Comment: Priorities are placed on _scheduled_ refresh tasks as opposed to workbook datasource refreshes like your script is doing. The reason for this is because schedules typically are, for example, on the hour - and many extracts can run at the same time. I, again, am not 100% sure here, but I assume when you call with a script it is equivalent to the "run now" option which essentially assigns priority 100. It would be worth checking with your Tableau team as to the order the refreshes took place in and even check the logs to see what priority was assigned. I think you're safe putting them in order.